# gmapping not working for LaserScan obtained from but_velodyne_proc

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using [but_velodyne_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/but_velodyne_proc#Installation) package to obtain 2d laser scan **sensor_msgs/LaserScan** from a 3d Velodyne **sensor_msgs/PointCloud2**. It seems that it works fine because I can visualize laser scan and point cloud in rviz. However, problem arises when I try to use this 360 degree laser scan data with [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) to obtain a 2d occupancy map using:

> rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=/velodyne/scan

It gives me following error:

> **slam_gmapping: /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-openslam-gmapping-0.1.0-2precise-20140617-1746/scanmatcher/scanmatcher.cpp:563: void GMapping::ScanMatcher::setLaserParameters(unsigned int, double*, const OrientedPoint&): Assertion `beams<2048' failed.
> Aborted (core dumped)**

The error of "beam 2048" is coming from [here](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/gmapping/html/scanmatcher_8h_source.html#l00010). Gmapping is working fine when I am using LaserScan from the lidar installed on my robot. Do you think this is because I am feeding 360 degree scan? I can see that scan header of the lidar is coming with angle_min: -2.35619449615 angle_max: 2.35619449615, whereas header of LaserScan obtained from Velodyne is angle_min: -3.14159274101 angle_max: 3.14159274101.
I am very beginner with all this stuff and do not understand the meaning of "LASER_MAXBEAMS 2048" defined in the header file. Your guideline to fix this problem is much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188700/gmapping-not-working-for-laserscan-obtained-from-but_velodyne_proc/) by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2014-08-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

scanmatcher in gmapping is limiting number of beams to [2048](https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping/blob/89290feea99cd4204ffe30fa46835540c22b7939/scanmatcher/scanmatcher.cpp#L563)

For your case

```
angle_min: -2.35619449615 angle_max: 2.35619449615
```

which is ~ 269 degrees and from launch file

```
 <param name="angular_res" value="0.1" />
```

it counts `2690 > 2048`.

Change resolution to 0.2 or 0.5 so that number of beams becomes < 2048.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on 2014-08-03**:
Thanks bvbdort :)

**Comment by [spacewandererer](https://answers.ros.org/users/34735/spacewandererer/) on 2018-05-16**:
Thanks bvbdort ! This worked. Also, thanks AsifA, I was using pointcloud_to_laserscan package earlier but it wasn't working for me. But this package works.

**Comment by [PKGosal](https://answers.ros.org/users/56803/pkgosal/) on 2020-07-19**:
Thank you so much! After spending more than 10 hours on troubleshooting, this was what I needed to address on my side too. Thanks again.